# Laravel app refreshes page on log in, in AWS?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ecs

I have a very strange situation. I have created a laravel app and running it in this Docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/richarvey/nginx-php-fpm

The app works perfectly fine locally using docker-compose and a local sidecar MySQL container, but as soon as I deploy into ECS, it has strange behavior. When I click login the page just refreshes and no backend calls are made.

The docker hub page for the container says that you will need to set the real ip address if using an aws elb - which I have done (https://gitlab.com/ric_harvey/nginx-php-fpm/blob/master/docs/nginx_configs.md#real-ip--x-forwarded-for-headers)

I've tried almost everything in nginx to test it's not that causing the problem and also have sticky sessions enabled. I've tried setting the domain name in the laravel conf session and nova file, I've even tried using database-driven sessions.

What else is interesting is if I set up the same configuration with laravel forge, add an ALB in front with a subdomain route53 DNS it works fine.

Thanks for any suggestions going forward.

Comment: Are you using relative urls? What is the url of href tag of the login on your AWS server? Secondly does it refresh when you click or when you click on login it goes to infinite loop or something ?

Comment: @MihirBhende thanks for getting back to me the path is relative to /admin/login.
And secondly, when you click login it refreshes the page, no post, just a straight up GET request back to the login page

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to add trusty proxies in 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies

and also force https in the provider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  /**
   * Bootstrap any application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function boot()
  {
      // force HTTPS
      URL::forceSchema('https');
  }

  /**
   * Register any application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function register()
  {
      //
  }
}
```